# How to debug my application exe at the client side

Tags: c#, windows

I am developing a windows application, that shows some perfomance issue at the client side.
So, I created a Debug Logger in file using this code after every line of code
C
           #if DEBUG
             LogwithTime("This Process completed");
           #endif

But I could not record the log, as the file is not running in the DEBUG mode... 
How can I put it in DEBUG mode so that I could get the code between #if DEBUG and  #endif to work?

Thanks

Comment: You have to compile the executable in debug mode and hand that (and any associated DLLs) over.

Comment: You might want to consider using a logging library like Log4Net.  Then you can set log levels for your application that controls what does  and does not get logged.

Comment: Or create a custom TraceSource which you write tracing information to...you can then have different app.config files defined to set up different TraceListeners to capture the tracing output to a file, console...and you can also change the switches on the TraceSource, so it doesn't generate any tracing output (i.e. listeners don't receive anything). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228993(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recompile the whole solution in Debug mode and send this to your client.

You can't just "put" it in Debug or Release mode. Code compiled in Release mode is optimised and it is not possible even from theoretical point of view to move it to Debug, e.g. your logging lines are not present on your clients machine.

Answer (score 3):

`#if DEBUG` only includes the code if you're doing the Debug build, and is omitted in the Release build (i.e. that's the whole point of the `#if DEBUG` preprocessor directive).

To include this logging code in release build what I'd do is change the pre-processor directive to something more meaningful, and then control it from project properties.  In other words, change your code to

```
#if INCLUDE_TIME_LOGGING LogwithTime("This Process completed"); #endif
```

Then go to project properties, and for Release build, put `INCLUDE_TIME_LOGGING` in Project->Build->Conditional compilation symbols.

Once you're done troubleshooting, then you can remove that from conditional compilation symbols, rebuild, and your code will be free from this debugging logging (and thus a bit more efficient).  Makes it very easy to control.

As others suggested, log4net is great for this as well, and wouldn't require rebuild as you can control it via config file.

That should do it!

Answer (score 2):

The DEBUG flag is set when you compile your application using the Debug Configuration. You have compiled your application using the Release Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, in this kind of situations, you can deliver the client with a patch that contains your dll in debug mode to get more detailed information about the problem that you have. Afterwards you can deliver the release dll again.

We deliver in some applications only debug dll if there is no real reason to deliver release dll.